# Inability to install expo or run it

Tags: react-native, macos, expo

I am using macOS Ventura 13.1

I cannot install expo. Every time I enter the command `npm install -g expo-cli`, I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/***/.npm/_logs/2023-06-19T18_30_12_325Z-debug-0.log
```

I've tried to get around this by doing `sudo npm install -g expo-cli`. This seems to allow me to download it with only warnings. However, when I later go into the correct folder and try to run `npx expo start` or `npm start`, I get this error:

```
WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the new local Expo CLI: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421.
Starting project at /Users/*****/ReactNativeCourse/WeatherApp
Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?
```

Afterward, when I run `npm install` to try and resolve the issue, I get another error similar to above.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: weatherapp@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"18.2.0" from react-native@0.71.8
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.71.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/williamwu/.npm/_logs/2023-06-19T18_43_08_612Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/*****/.npm/_logs/2023-06-19T18_43_08_612Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of troubleshooting, I was able to figure it out.

1. Firstly run :

   `sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/Whatevernameyouhave/.npm"`
2. After that, to create project use :

   `expo init projectName`

Also, when installing expo try to use this command :

`sudo npm i -g expo-cli`

Other things I tried that didn't work but might work for you:

- I manually uninstalled nodejs and reinstalled it.
- I uninstalled and reinstalled vscode.
- I uninstalled and reinstalled expo.